# converting string to list of int64

Tags: c#

On the client, I have an array of ints on which I call a ToString method; I'm then sending that string to the server via ajax.

On the server, I'm writing this:

```
var TestList = (from string s in TheString.Split(',')
                select Convert.ToInt64(s)).ToList<long>();
```

Is this going to crash if the incoming string actually contains unexpected values?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is a number that cannot be successfully parsed to a long?

Comment: I want to know about it and set a boolean to false; I'm sanitizing data that's coming from the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string contains unexpected values it could throw a `FormatException` or an `OverflowException` as mentioned in the documentation for [`Convert.ToInt64(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zahhahw.aspx).

To avoid the exception you could use `bool long.TryParse(string, out long)`.

```
List<long> testList = new List<long>();
foreach (string s in theString.Split(','))
{
    long number;
    if (long.TryParse(s, out number))
    {
        testList.Add(number);
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something?
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice. Anyway to make it fit as a one-liner with linq syntax?

Comment: I just think it reads better but of course the result is more important.

Comment: @frenchie You could always just remove all the linebreaks.

Comment: btw, is there a difference in putting the "long number;" line inside or outside the loop?

Comment: @frenchie: Yes, it changes the scope of the variable. In my opinion you should always use the smallest scope you can.

Comment: See my answer.  Just use a lambda expression.

Comment: @MarkByers: does it mean that each time the loop iterates the long is reinitialized?

Comment: @frenchie: No. It only means that the variable is valid within the scope that it is declared. It doesn't affect when the variable is initialized. The initialization is done by the `out` keyword which is inside the loop in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in a single statement, but you need the help of a helper method...

```
var TestList =
    (from string s in TheString.Split(',')
     let value = TryParseLong(s)
     where value != null
     select value.Value).ToList();

...

static long? TryParseLong(string s)
{
    long result;
    if (long.TryParse(s, out result))
        return result;
    return null;
}
```

Note: actually, you *could* do it without the helper method:

```
long value;
var TestList =
    (from string s in TheString.Split(',')
     where long.TryParse(s, out value)
     select value).ToList();
```

But it's not a good idea, because the query produces side effects, which could cause unexpected behavior if the query becomes more complex.

Comment: +1 I like this approach, but it won't completely solve the OP's issue (if you see the comments about setting a boolean to false)

Comment: @ReedCopsey: yes, I'm a big fan of one-liner simple solutions but I'm just realizing that for this one, the foreach works better.